# Microsoft purview which scan type should I use for scanning a remote web directory?

Tags: azure-purview, azure-information-protection

I'm looking for the best way to scan a web directory using Microsoft Purview. While configuring Microsoft Purview I was able to scan a local directory using an Azure data lake, but I couldn't find a way to make it work with a remote directory.

I found all of the type of scan : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/microsoft-purview-connector-overview.

There is a lot of different types of scan and I don't know which one to choose? or if what I want to do is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Remote directory cannot be scanned using Microsoft Purview. It is not supported as a data source yet. Would recommend filing a feature request in IDEAS forum here:

Microsoft Purview product IDEAS Forum: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/82d7bddb-fb24-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8

Related feedback logged by other users: [On-premise file servers](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/6e2c11f0-fc24-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8)

Comment: Alright, will do. Thanks!